# how to ask a kafka broker to send us its metrics?

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

We are going to replace our Activemq broker with Kafka broker. In activemq we could send a message to it so that it sends us its queues' metrics.
But I can't find a way in kafka to ask for its topic metrics. Can someone help me?

Comment: The answer is JMX. For the enterprise solution, you can look at Confluent Control Center

Answer (score 0):

Kafka metrics are of 3 types.

1. Kafka Server (Broker) metrics
2. Producer metrics
3. Consumer metrics

You can collect Kafka metrics using JMX (https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans).

For more information on collecting the metrics and monitoring those via a dashboard, read the following link, https://softwaremill.com/monitoring-apache-kafka-with-influxdb-grafana/